# How to get a string from a try block in an inner class

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes

I'm trying to set the label as the String received by the reader, in an inner class that implements ActionListener.
 But I get an unknown symbol error.
How could I reference that variable in an inner class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
public class DailyAdviceClient {
  JLabel label;
  JButton button;
  JFrame frame;
  JPanel mainPanel;

  public void gui() {
    frame = new JFrame("Daily Advice Client");
    button = new JButton("Get Advice");
    label = new JLabel("Text");
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(button);
    mainPanel.add(label);

    button.addActionListener(new AdviceListener());
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);

    frame.setSize(300,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
  public void go() {
    try {
      Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);

      InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

      String advice = reader.readLine();
      System.out.println("Today you should: " + advice);
      reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Hayt tumhari ki");
      System.out.print("I didn't think we would get to this stage. Please ");
      System.out.println("kill the developer. \n");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DailyAdviceClient client = new DailyAdviceClient();
    client.go();
    client.gui();
  }

  public class AdviceListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      label.setText(advice);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The string needs to be declared before the try block

Comment: Read about the scope of a variable for Java. It will only exist for the scope where it was declare (and the "sub scope")

Comment: You failed to start the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You cannot safely run the GUI on the main thread as you did here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easily be solved by applying the MVC pattern:

You only have a *Controller* and a *View*, but You'r missing a common *Model* both of them work on.

The simplest implementation would be to promote the local variable `advice` to be an *object member variable* serving as the *model*:

```
public class DailyAdviceClient {
  private String advice;
  // ...
  advice = reader.readLine();
  // ...
```

and converting the class `AdviceListener` into an *anonymous inner class* as a *lambda*:

```
button.addActionListener(ae->label.setText(advice));
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your string **advice** as instance/field variable :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
public class DailyAdviceClient {
  JLabel label;
  JButton button;
  JFrame frame;
  JPanel mainPanel;
  String advice;

  public void gui() {
    frame = new JFrame("Daily Advice Client");
    button = new JButton("Get Advice");
    label = new JLabel("Text");
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(button);
    mainPanel.add(label);

    button.addActionListener(new AdviceListener());
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);

    frame.setSize(300,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
  public void go() {
    try {
      Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);

      InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

      advice = reader.readLine();
      System.out.println("Today you should: " + advice);
      reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Hayt tumhari ki");
      System.out.print("I didn't think we would get to this stage. Please ");
      System.out.println("kill the developer. \n");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DailyAdviceClient client = new DailyAdviceClient();
    client.go();
    client.gui();
  }

  public class AdviceListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      label.setText(advice);
    }
  }
}
```